# How to inject FacesContext with JSF 2.3 and TomEE?

Tags: jsf, apache-tomee, facescontext, openwebbeans

I've been trying to use JSF 2.3 with TomEE server and I'm having problems using the `@Inject` annotation with the `FacesContext` object.

When I use it, i get the following exception while starting my TomEE server:

```
SEVERE: CDI Beans module deployment failed 
org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [javax.faces.context.FacesContext] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like some JSF2.3 features must be activated by setting the used JSF version.

Try setting JSF version by adding this empty class:

```
    import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig;

/**
 * The presence of the @FacesConfig annotation on a managed bean deployed within an application enables version specific
 * features. In this case, it enables JSF CDI injection and EL resolution using CDI.
 *
 */
@FacesConfig(version = FacesConfig.Version.JSF_2_3)
public class ConfigurationBean {
}
```

from `https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22094`